# Specific Pip installation problems

Tags: python, pip, python-3.2

I'm trying to install pip, but I need to install a version that is compatible with python 3.2 32 Bit.

I saw that pip versions above 8.0.0 removed support for Python 3.2. I need some help installing pip 7.1.2 (the version prior). I visited the page that has pip 7.1.2, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/7.1.2

On this page, there is only a .whl file and the source. How do I go about installing this specific version of pip, without a prior version of pip installed?

Comment: Why are you using Python 3.2?

Comment: Is compiling the pip version you want from source not an option?

Comment: @DanielRoseman because i'm using it for a specific purpose with pygame 3.2 (the most up to date version)

Comment: @tale852150 how do i go bout doing that? i do have the source but don't know how to compile it

Answer (score 0):

You can download the [pip 7.1.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/7.1.2) source distribution and run from there (is just plain python code, you don't need to compile anything). After extracting the tarball, you can install a package using:

```sh
$ cd pip-7.1.2
$ python -m pip install my-package
```

If you want to install pip itself:

```sh
$ python -m pip install pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Download `get-pip.py` using `wget` or `curl`
Then run `python get-pip.py`